# Easy question that I can't do: Find all continuous functions satisfying $\left\|\int_0^1 f\right\|= \int_0^1 \|f\|$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to find all *continuous* functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ satisfying:

$$\left\|\int_0^1 f\right\|= \int_0^1 \|f\|$$

Any hints?

I have tried lots of things, none of which have worked. I have found plenty of functions that work, but have no idea how to describe the entire set. I have tried writing the integral as Riemann sums and using the analogy of the vector triangle inequality, which wasn't helpful. I have tried looking at specific norms to get some necessary conditions, but didn't get far with that either. For $\mathbb R^1$ a necessary condition would be that $f$ is always positive or always negative.

Comment: Here's a hint. You can think of integrals as being like sums, so let's consider the analogous problem for finite sums. Suppose that $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. When is it the case that $\|v_1 + \cdots + v_n\| = \|v_1\| + \cdots + \|v_n\|$? This should at least hopefully give you a conjecture to work towards.

Comment: Is this the supremum norm?

Comment: Which norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are you using? Euclidean norm, maximum norm, $\ell^p$-norm, some other norm?

Comment: I do not understand the right hand side. There the norm is taken in the integrand so it does no longer depend on $x∈[0,1]$ so the integral is simply the norm of $f$. Or do you mean something else.

Comment: Does the question specifically say that this is Riemann integration? It would be easier to use Lebesgue integration and start with "Let S be the set of values on which f is positive (which is measurable because f is continuous)..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer depends on the used norm.

If we use $\lVert v\rVert_1 = \sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert v_k\rvert$, the equality becomes

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert = \int_0^1 \sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert f_k(x)\rvert\,dx = \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_0^1 \lvert f_k(x)\rvert\,dx.\tag{1}$$

Since for every $k$ the inequality

$$\biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert \leqslant \int_0^1 \lvert f_k(x)\rvert\,dx\tag{2}$$

holds, we have equality in $(1)$ if and only if we have equality in $(2)$ for every $k$, that is, if none of the components of $f$ changes sign.

If we use $\lVert v\rVert_{\infty} = \max \{ \lvert v_k\rvert : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$, the equality becomes

$$\max \left\{ \biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\right\} = \int_0^1 \max \left\{ \lvert f_k(x)\rvert : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\right\}\,dx. \tag{3}$$

If we then pick an $m$ such that

$$\biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_m(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert = \max \left\{ \biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\right\},$$

we see that we must have

$$\biggl\lvert \int_0^1 f_m(x)\,dx\biggr\rvert = \int_0^1 \lvert f_m(x)\rvert\,dx = \int_0^1 \max \left\{ \lvert f_k(x)\rvert : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\right\}\,dx,$$

which implies that $f_m$ doesn't change sign, and $\lvert f_k(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f_m(x)\rvert$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and all $k$ (let's call that a dominating component of $f$). So there must be at least one dominating component of $f$ that doesn't change sign. Conversely, one checks that if $f$ has a dominating component that doesn't change sign, then

$$\biggl\lVert\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\biggr\rVert_{\infty} = \int_0^1 \lVert f(x)\rVert_{\infty}\,dx.$$

Despite the answer depending on the used norm, there is a unified approach to finding the set of functions with the desired property.

First, we treat the trivial case. If $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = 0$, then the equality holds if and only if $f\equiv 0$. That follows easily from the continuity and positive definiteness of the norm.

So we may assume that

$$I := \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$

is not $0$ and the equality holds. Now we invoke a big theorem (Hahn-Banach) to note that there is a $\lambda \in (\mathbb{R}^n,\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert)'$ with $\lVert \lambda\rVert = 1$ and $\lambda(I) = \lVert I\rVert$.

Then we have

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx &= \biggl\lVert \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\biggr\rVert \tag{assumption}\\
&= \lambda\Biggl(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\Biggr)\\
&= \int_0^1 \lambda\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\,dx \tag{linearity of integral}\\
&\leqslant \int_0^1 \bigl\lvert \lambda\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr\rvert\,dx\\
&\leqslant \int_0^1\lVert\lambda\rVert\cdot \lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx.
\end{align}

Since the outer terms of the chain of inequalities are the same, we must have equality everywhere, and hence

$$\lambda\bigl(f(x)\bigr) = \lVert f(x)\rVert\tag{4}$$

for all $x\in [0,1]$. Conversely, if $4$ holds for some $\lambda$ with $\lVert \lambda\rVert = 1$, then we have the equality $\lVert I\rVert = \int_0^1 \lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx$.

This also works for $f\equiv 0$, and we can summarise:

$$\biggl\lVert\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\biggr\rVert = \int_0^1 \lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx$$

if and only if there is a $\lambda \in (\mathbb{R}^n,\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert)'$ with $\lVert\lambda\rVert = 1$ such that for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $f(x) \in C(\lambda)$, where $C(\lambda)$ is the cone

$$C(\lambda) = \{ v\in \mathbb{R}^n : \lambda(v) = \lVert v\rVert\}.$$

If the norm is an $\ell^p$-norm, $\lVert v\rVert = \left(\sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert v_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$ for some $1 < p < \infty$, the cones $C(\lambda)$ are easily described.

In particular the Euclidean case - $p = 2$ - should now not pose a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. The norm was not specified so presumably it means $f$ must work for any norm we choose to define.

Comment: More likely that it was tacitly assumed to be the Euclidean norm. It's common to use that when nothing else is specified.

Comment: I would have thought that except the professor said in lectures that he received emails complaining that the question didn't say what the norm is, and he said he did that intentionally. So I imagine I would just be assuming the norm axioms.

Comment: No, $f$ need not be constant. Any $f$ of the form $f(t) = g(t)\cdot v$, where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g\colon [0,1]\to [0,+\infty)$ is continuous, works for every norm. These are the only ones that work for every norm, but for specific norms, there also can be other functions where you have equality.

Comment: To have a norm, you would need to take absolute values, $\sup \lvert f_1\rvert + \dotsc$. But you'd get a norm on a space of functions, not on $\mathbb{R}^n$, as you need from the problem statement. (Since $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Of course if you allow different norms [on different or the same spaces] on the sides of the equation, more things can happen. But the sensible interpretation is that on both sides you use the same norm. With domain $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Answer (score 0):

So there is a way to do this without using any big theorems (like Hahn-Banach).

First we will get a necessary condition. Suppose that $$\left\| \int_0^1 f\right\|= \int_0^1 \|f\|$$

If we take $\| \cdot \|$ to be the Euclidean norm, then we can write this as

$$\left(\int_0^1 f\right)\cdot \left( \int_0^1 f\right) = \left\| \int_0^1 f\right\|\int_0^1 \|f\|$$

Or equivalently

$$\int_0^1 \left( f \cdot \int_0^1 f \right)= \int_0^1 \left(\left\| \int_0^1 f\right\| \|f\|\right) \tag 1$$

Now by Cauchy-Schwarz we have $\displaystyle  f \cdot \int_0^1 f  \le \left\| \int_0^1 f\right\| \|f\|$

So for $(1)$ to hold we require that $\displaystyle  f \cdot \int_0^1 f  = \left\| \int_0^1 f\right\| \|f\|$, since we are given that $f$ is continuous.

This occurs if and only if $$f(t) = \lambda(t) \int_0^1 f(t) \, \mathrm d t$$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar.

This implies that $f(t) = \lambda(t) v$ where $v$ is a constant vector. This turns out to be sufficient for any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ if $\lambda$ does not change sign for all $t \in [0,1]$, since

\begin{align}\left \| \int_0^1 \lambda(t) v \, \mathrm d t \right \| &= \left \| v \int_0^1 \lambda(t) \, \mathrm d t \right \| \\ &=  \| v \| \left| \int_0^1 \lambda(t) \, \mathrm d t \right|\\ &= \|v\|\int_0^1 |\lambda(t)| \, \mathrm d t \\ &= \int_0^1 \| \lambda(t) v \| \, \mathrm d t
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$. So $g'(x)=f(x)$, and $\vert\vert g'(x)\vert\vert =\vert\vert f(x)\vert\vert$. The hypothesis is $\vert \vert g(1)-g(0)\vert\vert=\int_0^1 \vert\vert g'(t)\vert\vert dt$. So your ppt holds iff the curve $g : [0,1]\to \bf R^n$ realize the distance between its extreme points (a geodesic). For a strictly convex normed space, the geodesic between two points is unique and is a line segment, and $f$ also describe injectively a line segment. For other spaces such as $d_\infty$ on $\bf R^2$ the "sup" norm, you can have plenty of geodesics between two points : the geodesic between $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are of length 2, and $[(-1,1)(0,x)\cup [(0,x),(1,1)]$ is a one parameter family of geodesics of the same length.